# Using SignalR for logging across many projects - Logging is empty and no exceptions thrown?

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging, signalr, nlog

I am currently using NLog for our logging mechanism for all of our applications. I am trying to integrate SignalR for real-time notifications. I have found what seems to be solid library: [NLog.SignalR](https://github.com/toddmeinershagen/NLog.SignalR).

As a test, I have a Console and WPF application that I would like to record log events. I have added the necessary libraries and have incorporated (copy/paste) the [NLog.SignalR.Sample.Web](https://github.com/toddmeinershagen/NLog.SignalR/tree/master/src/NLog.SignalR.Sample.Web) project from the above library. I have pretty much simulated the settings/changes for my Console and WPF applications to mimic the library's other sample which is a [Console](https://github.com/toddmeinershagen/NLog.SignalR/tree/master/src/NLog.SignalR.Sample.Command) application.

With all of the changes in place (what I believe needed to be changed), no logging is occurring. I have even enabled the `throwExceptions=true` setting in the NLog.config file as per the recommendation in the documentation for trying to figure out why logging is not happening and nothing is being thrown. I'm sure I am missing something silly but can't figure out exactly what it may be.

Here are some bits of the things I did when trying to implement this library into my project:

1. Created a WPF project targeting .NET 4.5.
2. Added NuGet package for NLog (3.1)
3. Added NuGet package for NLog.SignalR (2.0)
4. Added existing Web project from the NLog.SignalR library to my solution.
5. Added an NLog.config file to my WPF project. Settings are very similar to the sample's console application.
6. Enabled `throwExceptions=true` in NLog.config file (w/o luck)

I am not sure what pieces of code might be the culprit so I have avoided pasting any code on here since I would be shooting in the dark I feel. I will certainly paste any code on here if anyone would like to see certain parts. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Although you have included NLog.config file but when you compile Console app..this config file is not copied to Bin Debug/Release directory so nothing is happening to you.. Just copy your own created config file to debug/release directory.. it will start working.. or In Solution Explorer select NLog.config and set Copy to output directory to Copy always.